# when is default mode active

Tags: neuroscience, brain, well-being

AFAIK default mode is important for our well being since as I am concerned one of its functions is to make sense of things we learned, experienced, etc.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_mode_network) is says default mode is active when person is at wakeful rest.
Also it says default mode **is active** when person is **not focused on the outside world**.

My question is: is default mode active when I am not focused on outside world, however, maybe internally thinking/concerned about some specific problems/issues?